# Android: Deleted file but user data not free up. How can fix?

Tags: java, android

[image]My app can get image add in to folder "photo" and delete it, but after deleted image in folder "photo"  user data not free up although i checked files explorer in android studio and log really deleted. I save the file in internal storage (app private storage) not external. How i can fix?

```
public class InternalStorageHelper {

public static String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage, Context context, String fileName) {
   
    File directory = new File(context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir, "photo");
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs();
    }
    // Create imageDir
    File myPath = new File(directory, fileName+ ".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    if (myPath.exists()) {
        myPath.delete();
    }
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }

    return myPath.getAbsolutePath();
}


public static Bitmap loadImageFromStorage(String path) {
    try {
        File f = new File(path);

        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        return b;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static void deleteFile(String path) {
    File fdelete = new File(path);
    if (fdelete.exists()) {
        if (fdelete.delete()) {
            Log.d("progress", "file Deleted :" + path);
        } else {
            Log.d("progress", "file not Deleted :" + path);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: User data does not count external folders

Comment: @Rohit Kumar. That data dir is pretty internal.

Comment: Sorry but i save the file in internal storage (app private storage) not external.